# Why does rust produce completely different assembly with and without pub and #[no_mangle]?

Tags: assembly, rust

The rust code in question is:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
fn add(a: isize, b: isize) -> isize {
    a + b
}
```

It produces the following assembly code when used with rustc command `rustc add.rs --crate-type=lib --emit=asm -C opt-level=z`:

```
    .text
    .file   "add.3a1fbbbh-cgu.0"
    .section    .text.add,"ax",@progbits
    .globl  add
    .type   add,@function
add:
    .cfi_startproc
    leaq    (%rdi,%rsi), %rax
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   add, .Lfunc_end0-add
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

And the following without `#[no_mangle]`:

```
    .text
    .file   "add.3a1fbbbh-cgu.0"

    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

Why is this so ? Shouldn't it just change `add` to something like `_Zaddm` without no-mangle ?

Comment: Add `pub` to your function and update your question please.

Comment: Please do not put *answers* in your *question*. You are welcome to answer your own question below and even accept that answer. This is better because it allows additional answers and those answers to be voted on by the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `#[no_mangle]` there is no code emitted at all (what you see are just assembler directives, there is no actual code). I'm guessing that the compiler decides that the function will always be inlined, so there is no need to really emit code for it (especially since you're optimizing for size and adding the two values inline will never be bigger than calling the function).

The only reason why you would want `#[no_mangle]` is if you are planning to call the function from outside Rust. Such a call can't be inlined for obvious reason, so I assume the compiler does emit the code to make these external calls possible.